# How to get "IDENTIFY_DEVICE_DATA" of a USB HDD?

Tags: delphi, usb, ioctl

I am writing a HDD tool that read SMART data and change APM/AAM of a drive. I started with the internal disks and everything seems to be ok. I get a handle with `CreateFile` and `\\.\PhysicalDriveX`, and use `DeviceIoControl` with `IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH` to get `IDENTIFY_DEVICE_DATA` of a drive like this:

```
function GetDriveHandle(Name:String; var hDrive:THandle):Boolean;
begin
 hDrive:=CreateFile(PChar(Name), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
  FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
 Result:=hDrive<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
end;

function GetIdentify(hDrive:THandle; var Data:IDENTIFY_DEVICE_DATA):Boolean;
var atpexb: ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX_WITH_BUFFERS;
    bytesRet: DWord;
begin
 bytesRet:=0;
 FillChar(atpexb,SizeOf(atpexb),0);
 atpexb.Length:=SizeOf(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX);
 atpexb.AtaFlags:=ATA_FLAGS_DATA_IN;
 atpexb.DataTransferLength:=512;
 atpexb.TimeOutValue:=3;
 atpexb.DataBufferOffset:=SizeOf(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX);
 atpexb.CurrentTaskFile.Command:=WIN_IDENTIFYDEVICE;
 atpexb.CurrentTaskFile.SectorCount:=1;
 Result:=DeviceIoControl(hDrive, IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH, @atpexb, SizeOf(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX),
  @atpexb, SizeOf(atpexb), bytesRet, nil);
 if Result then Move(atpexb.DataBuff, Data, SizeOf(Data));
end;
```

But if I try this on a USB HDD it's not working. I get "Error 50: The request is not supported". Ok, I researched more on the internet and I found out that I need to open a special handle to the USB device with something like this: "\?\usb#vid_1058&pid_1078#575856314541353752543645#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}". I used the device path of my USB HDD to get the handle but when I try to use it with `DeviceIoControl/IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH` I get the same error: "The request is not supported".